# can't create super user with a CustomUserManager in django 3.2.2

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a superuser but no matter what changes I make, I still get this error:

> File "D:\python\gambling_game\gamegambling\users\models.py", line 40, in create_superuser
>
> return self.create_user(self, email, pseudo, first_name, last_name, birth_date, password, **other_fields)
>
> TypeError: create_user() takes 7 positional arguments but 8 were given

I went through the code multiple times but couldn't spot the error.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser , PermissionsMixin , BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, pseudo, first_name, last_name, birth_date, password, **other_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_('Please enter an email address'))
    email = self.nomalize_email(email)

    if bith_isValid(birth_date):
        birth_date = birth_date
    else:
        raise ValueError(_('birth date not valid'))
    
    user = self.models(email = email, pseudo = pseudo , first_name = first_name,
                        last_name = last_name, birth_date = birth_date, **other_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, pseudo, first_name, last_name, birth_date, password, **other_fields):

    other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True')
    if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True')
    if other_fields.get('is_active') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_active=True')
    
    return self.create_user(self, email, pseudo, first_name, last_name, birth_date, password, **other_fields)






def bith_isValid(date):
   present = datetime.date.today()
   return date < present

class CustomUser (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    pseudo = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    #prenom
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    #nom
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    USER_GENDER = [ ('M', 'Male'),
                  ('F', 'Female'),
                  ('NB', 'Non-Binary')]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = USER_GENDER, null = True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    profil_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank = True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['pseudo','first_name','last_name','birth_date']

    def __str__(self):
       return self.pseudo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not pass self to the function call self... 
change this:

```py
   return self.create_user(self, email, ps...)
```

to this:

```py
   return self.create_user(email, ps
```

PS: Probably a copy paste error ;) we all do it.

Comment: @uriel Funny how one can look at that over and over and never see it until someone else comes to help.. happens all the time. Glad to help ;)